# Set Xcode automatic signing to false and set provision profile and certificate with fastlane match and gym

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fusetools, fastlane-gym

We use [Fusetools](http://fusetools.com) to build an app. Using the command `uno build --target=ios --configuration=Release` we generate a new `myapp.xcodeproj` file for the app.

When I open the `.xcodeproj` in Xcode IDE manually I see the `Automatically manage signing` checkbox is selected. We then use Fastlane match to get certificates and select appstore certificate manually in Xcode. This all works fine.

Now - we try to build this using a CI provider like [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io) using a headless build process. Then everything stops at the same point. our `.xcodeproj` has `Automatically manage signing` checkbox is selected.

Our Fastfile looks like this:

```
disable_automatic_code_signing(path: "../myapp.xcodeproj")

match(git_url: "git@github.com:MyRepo/match.git",
      app_identifier: "com.myapp.myapp",
      type: "appstore",
      readonly: true)

gym(
      workspace: "myapp.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "MyApp",
      export_method: "app-store",
      xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='match AppStore
      com.myapp.myapp'"
)
```

In our `Fastfile` we try to disable automatic signing first, the in gym - pass in parameter `xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='match AppStore com.myapp.myapp'"` to set the provisioning profile before build.

I then get this from Bitrise CI monitor:

`Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'`

I can reproduce this if running locally trying to set automatic signing to false and do the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

`xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='match AppStore com.myapp.myapp'"`

This approach doesn't work well any more since apps might have multiple targets. Instead check out the [Xcode setup guide](https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/xcode-project/) that describes that you can use environment variables, that are being filled by *match*, for each target's provisioning profile name option